# Where and how to store access token for using in spring boot client application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am working on a project in which I need to get resource with access token. To acquire the access token I was given an url (ex. https://remoteservice/login) and credentials (login and password). To obtain access token I created a class TokenObtainer.

```
@Data
@Component
public class TokenObtainer {
   @Value("${token_url}")
   private String tokenUrl;

   @Value("${service_user}")
   private String username;

   @Value("${service_password}")
   private String password;

   RestTemplate restTemplate;

   @Autowired
   public TokenObtainer(RestTemplate restTemplate){
     this.restTemplate=restTemplate;
   }


   public String obtainToken(){
       HttpHeaders header=new HttpHeaders();
       header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
       JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
       obj.put("username", username);
       obj.put("password", password);
       HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(obj.toString(), header);
       String res=restTemplate.postForObject(tokenUrl,request,String.class);
       return res;
   }

}
```

I am thinking of injecting TokenObtainer class in the controller class and set access token in session.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service")
public class GnkServiceController {

private final TokenObtainer tokenObtainer;

@Autowired
public GnkServiceController(TokenObtainer tokenObtainer) {
    this.tokenObtainer = tokenObtainer;
}




@GetMapping("/test")
public String getTokenn(HttpServletRequest request){
    String token=tokenObtainer.obtainToken();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("access_token",token);
}

}
```

I believe this is not right solution.

So I would like to know if there is any context in which I can set access token by invoking aforementioned class then call it when required or other recommended methods to store access token?

Comment: can you clarify your needs? it seems like you're trying to obtain a token and send it to a client. if you're trying to login a user from the frontend you should take a closer look at spring security and your WebSecurityConfiguration.

Comment: The task I am working on is about integration on the backend. I have to integrate a secured rest api. When I want to call the api I need to obtain access token first thereafter request the resource with it. Every time getting access token to request the resource doesn't seem right way. The access token should be kept somewhere unless it expires. It is said to be expired in an hour. So every hour I should obtain access token and store it.

Comment: take a look at spring security 5. it has specific modules for oauth2 usage. By providing your oauth2-configuration via properties the most should be done. see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#introduction

Comment: in general your token should have an expiry date. you can try https://jwt.io/ to see what your token contains